# Wordpress - Assign Student Roll Numbers on Form Submission

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, forms

I am working on an academy website here at www.grmaedu.com
Web Specs: Built on Wordpress with the following plugins, Visual Form Builder Pro & Revolution Slider

So i have managed to do 90% of the work. My query is I want to assign automatic roll numbers to students who are submitting the application form here at www.grmaedu.com/application

Here are the remaining things I want to do:

1. Automatically assign Roll Number to students "after or on " form submission
2. Submit the form to the concerned mySql Database, Right now it emails correctly to the designated email address with no issues. All thanks to Visual Form Builder Pro
3. The date picker field is not working in the application form(I even updated my jQueryUI file)

I hope the provided details are enough for the solution.

Comment: Can you please specify in detail what you mean by *roll number*? Also, it's better not to put several questions in one post on Stack Overflow.

Comment: By roll number i mean a unique number assigned to a student

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured a way out. Here are the steps which i performed.

- I installed a WP Plugin named **Contact Form DB.** This plugin saves all the form submitted values and stores them in a mySQL database.
- I opened up phpmyadmin to see how it was stored and found it in one of the tables. I noticed that each entry had an unique id number. That is what I was trying to do. This plugin made it easier for me.
- Then i created a Page template file name rollnumber.php and inserted the following code in

  ```
  <?php

  /* Define Connection properties */

  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "grmaedu_wp2";
  $password = "******";
  $dbname = "grmaedu_wp2";

  // Create connection
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

  $sql = "SELECT entries_id FROM `wp_vfb_pro_entries` ORDER BY entries_id DESC LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $a = $row["entries_id"];
  $a++;
  echo "<h3>Your Roll Number assigned is: " . $a . "</h3>";
      //echo "id: " . $row["entries_id"] . "<br>";
  }
  } else {
  echo "0 results";
  }

  mysqli_close($conn);
  ?>
  ```
- So now when the page loads it automatically fetches the unique id and adds 1 to the last submitted id and voila a new roll number is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Index key is the best option to set as roll number. because it is unique and then you  can get user data directly form this id.

```
<?php

/* Define Connection properties */

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "grmaedu_wp2";
$password = "******";
$dbname = "grmaedu_wp2";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT entries_id FROM `wp_vfb_pro_entries` ORDER BY entries_id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

echo "<h3>Your Roll Number assigned is: " . mysqli_insert_id() . "</h3>";
    //echo "id: " . mysql_insert_id() . "<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```